# Queue build on specific agent based on custom parameter

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a build definition with a custom process parameter. If set to true, I'd like the build to queue up on a specific agent, essentially overriding any agent name that's set in the definition. I'd rather not use tags because I don't think they'll be used properly, plus this seems more dynamic in nature. I'm thinking this could be done in the build process template somehow. Just not sure how to accomplish it.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? tags are perfect for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the build process template to look at your custom workflow argument, and change the value of the AgentSettings.Name prior to the Run On Agent activity.

Comment: Oh, nice! I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Dylan, I thought I might be able to do this in an IF sequence and then assign a new value to that property. The problem is I'm not sure how to get at the agent name property.

Comment: I updated the answer, you modify the AgentSettings workflow argument.

Comment: Got it! So here is how I am doing it. I dropped an IF activity right before the Run On Agent activity and added an Assign activity that basically says, if my custom argument is true then assign ACME01* to AgentSettings.Name.